# Health Insurance in Austria and "Fragebogen zur Unfallerhebung"

Tags: health-insurance, austria

I'm from Italy and I've moved in Austria. Since I wasn't born in this country I don't know the language well, and I don't know how stuffs work here.

I felt down while skiing and the doctor gave me some days of rest to recover. But now I also got a letter from TGKK asking me if I was drunk, it there is any witness and so on..

I feel a bit disappointed, since it's a private insurance, and I wonder if they are trying to find a tricky excuse to avoid paying.

Should I ask the help of a lawyer? Are there institutions which can help me?

What are this questions finalized to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find a convenient official source clearly explaining it all but apparently this is a standard questionnaire that they send for all accidents leading to sick days. If someone else appears to bear some responsibility for the accident, they could try to recover the costs of those sick days from that person.

According to what I read, not filling it in, misrepresenting the events or deliberately omitting relevant information could lead your insurer to claim back from you any payments they made on your behalf. I would guess that evidence that you were grossly negligent could also have adverse consequences for you.